# Can we create an HBase namespace through REST api?

Tags: rest, hbase

We can create an `HBase` table through `REST api` (i.e., `http://{hbase-rest-server-ip:port}/{table-name}/schema`), but I haven't found a `REST api` through which we can create an `HBase namespace`. Is there such an `api` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't yet.

As it happens, Last day a bug was raised in the `HBase` jira for it!

[HBASE-14147](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-14147)

Answer (score 1):

POST `http://{hbase-rest-server-ip:port}/namespaces/{new namespace name}`
(No body required)
This should return HTTP/1.1 201 Created and not a lot else. If it returns 401 try using PUT instead!
Tables without a namespace (and colon) go into the 'default' namespace
To create or access a table in a specific namespace use a colon eg. {namespace name}:{table name}

To list all namespaces GET
`{hbase-rest-server-ip:port}/namespaces/`
To list tables within a namespace GET
`http://{hbase-rest-server-ip:port}/namespaces/tester/tables`
Note: Default port seems to be 8070
Example: using curl for hbase server on 10.10.10.1 port 8070
**Create new namespace** "new_name_space":

```
curl -vi -X POST "http://10.10.10.1:8070/namespaces/new_name_space"
```

**Create new table in namespace** "new_table" with column families "family1" and "family2" namespace "new_name_space":

```
curl -vi -X POST \
         -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
         -d '{"name":"new_name_space:new_table","ColumnSchema":[{"name":"family1"},{"name":"family2"}]}"' \
         "http://10.10.10.1:8070/new_name_space:new_table/schema"
```

More info: 
https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/admin_hbase_rest_api.html